# Facebook application instance creation not working for every users

Tags: facebook, instance

I have the following issue that drives me crazy. I use the sample code published with the Facebook PHP SDK (https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) for identifying a user. It works fine for most of my test users but for some users, the instance creation does not work. I’ve tried with the same machine and different machines, it does not change anything. Each user is correctly set as test user in my dev account.

What could be the cause? 
Many thanks in advance.

```
    require '../lib/facebook.php';

    // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXX',
      'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    ));

    // Get User ID
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) {
      try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
    }

    // Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
    if ($user) {
      $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    } else {
      $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'scope' => 'publish_stream, publish_actions',   
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxx/' 
    ));
    }
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
      <head>
        <title>php-sdk</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>php-sdk</h1>

        <?php if ($user): ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
        <?php else: ?>
          <div>
            Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
            <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>" target="_top">Login with Facebook</a>
          </div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <h3>PHP Session</h3>
        <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

        <?php if ($user): ?>
          <h3>You</h3>
          <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

          <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
          <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
        <?php else: ?>
          <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
        <?php endif ?>

        </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. The problem was not related to the code. It was due to the fact that the test users bypassed the notification requesting to accept the invitation and instead entered directly the app url.

You have to delete the test user and recreate it. Then the test user will recieve a new notification and will then have to accept it.